# Disk /dev/mapper/VolGroup doesn't contain a valid partition table

Tags: lvm

How to fix "Disk /dev/mapper/VolGroup doesn't contain a valid partition table"

```
[root@localhost _work]# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 160.0 GB, 160041885696 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 19457 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x13159c87

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1          64      512000   83  Linux
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sda2              64       19458   155777024   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root: 156.8 GB, 156766306304 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 19059 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_swap: 2113 MB, 2113929216 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 257 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_swap doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

Comment: Please compose an answer and mark it as "accepted".  Changing the title to [Resolved] is not the preferred method here.

Comment: There's nothing to fix. It's just that fdisk doesn't understand lvm stuff. Try `sudo parted /dev/sda print all` and see no errors reported.

Answer (score 7):

You don't fix it.  It isn't supposed to have a valid partition table, the filesystem is directly on the block device.  It is a logical volume.  Just ignore fdisk complaining about devices that aren't disks.
The `fdisk -l` command output is almost completely worthless against any `/dev/mapper` devices.